# Repaint method isn't working in time

Tags: java

I'm making a game in Java, and the `repaint()` method is misbehaving in a very odd way. Basically, I need to repaint the board before getting the AI's move. Here is my method where I'm calling it:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();

    int button = e.getButton();
    if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 || button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        int mouseR = (mouseY / SIZE);
        int mouseC = (mouseX / SIZE);

        if (mouseR >= 0 && mouseC >= 0 &&
                mouseR < board.length && mouseC < board[0].length) {
            if (board[mouseR][mouseC] == 3) {
                makeMove(mouseR, mouseC, playerColor);
                getValidMoves((playerColor % 2) + 1);
                repaint();
                getAIMove();
            }
        }

    }
    repaint();
}
```

`getAIMove()` is designed so it waits for a couple of seconds before making the move, so the player can see the results of their move before they see those of the AI. Unfortunately, although I call `repaint()` before `getAIMove()`, what happens is more like this: the player clicks where they want to move. Nothing appears to happen for a few seconds, then the results of the player's move AND the AI's move are displayed on the screen. What's going on?

Comment: I think you should rethink the application design to a more standard game loop. Your repaint shouldn't be dependend on game logic or user input.http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-the-game-loop/

Comment: you have a repaint() at the end of your method too, repaint() getAIMove() repaint() automatically

Comment: @JRowan Yes, I was trying different things because I didn't know what was going on. I'll take it out as I edit for efficiency, etc. Right now I'm just trying to get the code working :)

Comment: @JohannisK All the loop containing the first call is saying is "only repaint if the user does something." AFAIK, all this should do is make my program slightly more efficient (once the second `repaint()` is removed). Furthermore, this game is turn-based, and that link describes making a real-time game.

Comment: Hi KnightOfNi, off course it's not necesary to repaint 30 frames per second for a turn based game. The concept of the gameloop still applies though. It means you have a seperation between gamelogic and rendering which keeps the code clean. For a turn based game I would use something like Start -> Wait for user input -> update all involved gameobjects -> Draw -> Stop

Answer (score 2):

All the code in your `mouseClicked()` event handler will run on the special AWT/Swing Thread.

`repaint()` does not repaint the GUI immediately - it *schedules a repaint*, (see [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)) which will also run on the Swing thread - but not until your event handler has finished - the Swing thread can only do one thing at a time!

So you won't see the results of `getAIMove()` until afterwards.

You probably need to run the `getAIMove()` logic in a separate background thread, then update the GUI (which must be done in the Swing thread, using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or the `SwingWorker` helper class.)

Or, you could schedule the AI to run on the Swing thread, using `invokeLater()` - it will then run after the first `repaint()`. However, this method is undesirable (unless the AI is very fast), because your GUI will be unresponsive until the Swing thread becomes free again to handle repaints.

See also the Java tutorials on these topics:

- [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Worker threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Knowing what was going on 'under the hood' really helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A friend and I figured out a little trick to beat the queue described by @DNA - here's my new code:

```
public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e )
   {
      mouseX = e.getX();
      mouseY = e.getY();

      int button = e.getButton();
      if(button == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 || button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
      {
         int mouseR = (mouseY/SIZE);
         int mouseC = (mouseX/SIZE);

         if(mouseR >=0 && mouseC >= 0 && mouseR < board.length && mouseC < board[0].length)
         {
            if (board[mouseR][mouseC] == 3){
               makeMove(mouseR, mouseC, playerColor);
            }
         }

      } 
      repaint();
   }

   public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e )
   {
      int button = e.getButton();
      if(button == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 || button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
      {
         int mouseR = (mouseY/SIZE);
         int mouseC = (mouseX/SIZE);

         if(mouseR >=0 && mouseC >= 0 && mouseR < board.length && mouseC < board[0].length)
         {
            if (board[mouseR][mouseC] == playerColor){
               getValidMoves((playerColor % 2) + 1);
               getAIMove();
               getValidMoves(playerColor);
            }
         }

      } 
      repaint();
   }
```

By doing the player's move when the mouse is pressed, and waiting to do the AI's move until the mouse is released, the program is allowed to complete the Swing thread and repaint the board. Thanks for all of your help!